# Another way to say "to-do list"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any synonym for **to-do list** without the word 'list'?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please include a sample sentence where you want to use the word, as indicated [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info); there's another checklist at the bottom of that page you might want to consider as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*agenda* might work here:

> a list or outline of things to be considered or done

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agenda))</sub>

It is a Latin word literally meaning "things to do", but it's still in use in modern English.

Comment: I would be very thankful to have other words except *to-do list* and *agenda*. At least were I live, *agenda* has always a smell of "evil secret plans". I know this is absolutely not the mainstream understanding, but still...

Answer (score 1):

"order of the day,
agenda,
calendar,
docket,
frame,
lineup,
program of operation,
schedule,
schedule of operation,
schema,
things to be done,
time,
time scheme,
timetable"
according to https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/to-do%20list.